# The best way to build a list

Tags: html

I am wondering which tags to use to build a list with 1 parent and 2 subcategories, all are 3 cats. Is it span and 2 uls or span, a and a ul, is it a, span and a ul?

Comment: For a list, use `<ul>` and `<li>`. Nothing else.

Comment: @Konerak: Or `<ol>`, if necessary.

Comment: thanks konerak.. you are useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ul>` (or `<ol>`) and `<li>` are used to create lists.

`<span>`, `<a>` and other tags are used for other purposes.

```
<ul>
    <li>Category 1</li>
    <li>Category 2
        <ol>
            <li>2-1</li>
            <li>2-2
                <ul>
                    <li>2-2-1</li>
                    <li>2-2-2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ol>
    </li>
</ul>
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/efitid/2

Answer (score 1):

I dont even think you need the `<span>`.

Try something like this:

```
<ul>
     <li>Parent
          <ul>
               <li>Sub Cat</li>
          </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: this helps with 2 categories.. I need 3 like the one rocket answered

Comment: it's the same thing -- you can add more nested `<ul>`s (or `<ol>`s) if you'd like, either under the parent `<li>`, or after the sub category `<li>`.

Answer (score 1):

The common way to build lists in HTML is to use nested lists:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    Parent
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>Child</li>
      <li>Child</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Whatever you put in your `<li>` items is up to you - you do not need a `<span>` element. If your list contains links, put the `<a>` element inside your `<li>` element.

You can also take a look at this [nested list example](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listutorial/sub01.htm).

Ohh, and dont forget to write [semantic code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_Web). You should wrap your menu in a `<nav></nav>` block to indicate that it is a navigation element. (I'm guessing you're creating some kind of menu).